# Find probability

Tags: probability, statistics

A die is rolled repeatedly. What is the probability that 3 will show up before 6?

My thoughts: 
P(3 before 6) = 1- P(no 3 before 6). 
P(no 3 before 6)= any of { 1,2,4,5} before 6 = 1/3.
Therefore, P(3 before 6)= 2/3.

Comment: What is the probability that 6 will show up before 3? If you swap the face 3 and 6 of the dice, will this probability change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need not bother about numbers other than $3$ and $6$ at all as they don't affect the result !

And then, quite obviously, P(3 comes before 6) = P(6 comes before 3) = $\dfrac12$

Answer (score 0):

The number of permutations of 2 rolled dice is

$$ nPr(2, 6) = \frac{6!}{(6-2)!} = 30 $$

So the number of possible orders when you sequentially role two dice is 30.  The probability of any particular order (eg. 1 then 2, 3 then 6, 6 then 3) is $1/30$.

What you did is you tried to figure out the probability that 3 comes before six *given* that the second one is six.  However, $2/3$ is not the answer to that, because that is intuitively $1/6$.

Comment: Your answer is incorrect.  Please read the solution posted by true blue anil.